# adding a row to a data frame in long format

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Given a dataframe `df` like below

```
text <- "
parameter,car,qtr,val
a,a3,FY18Q1,23
b,a3,FY18Q1,10000
a,a3,FY18Q2,14
b,a3,FY18Q2,12000
a,cla,FY18Q1,15
b,cla,FY18Q1,12000
c,cla,FY18Q1,5.5
a,cla,FY18Q2,26
b,cla,FY18Q2,10000
c,cla,FY18Q2,6.2
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

I want to add a row with parameter `b_diff` for each `car, qtr` combination with `val` as difference of parameter `b` for two consecutive `qtr`. The `qtr` ascending order is `FY18Q1, FY18Q2`. For the first `qtr` which is `FY18Q1`, the `val` for `b_diff` shall be NA as there is no `previous` `qtr`.

The expected output is as below.

```
parameter   car qtr val
a   a3  FY18Q1  23
b   a3  FY18Q1  10000
b_diff  a3  FY18Q1  NA
a   a3  FY18Q2  14
b   a3  FY18Q2  12000
b_diff  a3  FY18Q2  2000
a   cla FY18Q1  15
b   cla FY18Q1  12000
c   cla FY18Q1  5.5
b_diff  cla FY18Q1  NA
a   cla FY18Q2  26
b   cla FY18Q2  10000
c   cla FY18Q2  6.2
b_diff  cla FY18Q2  -2000
```

How do I go about doing this with `dplyr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr). We can create a group ID using `group_indices` and based on that to split the data frame, summarize the data and then combine them. `df5` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(GroupID = group_indices(., car, qtr))

df3 <- df2 %>%
  filter(parameter %in% "b") %>%
  group_by(car) %>%
  mutate(val = val - lag(val), parameter = "b_diff") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  split(f = .$GroupID)

df4 <- df2 %>% split(f = .$GroupID)

df5 <- map2_dfr(df4, df3, bind_rows) %>% select(-GroupID)

df5
#    parameter car    qtr     val
# 1          a  a3 FY18Q1    23.0
# 2          b  a3 FY18Q1 10000.0
# 3     b_diff  a3 FY18Q1      NA
# 4          a  a3 FY18Q2    14.0
# 5          b  a3 FY18Q2 12000.0
# 6     b_diff  a3 FY18Q2  2000.0
# 7          a cla FY18Q1    15.0
# 8          b cla FY18Q1 12000.0
# 9          c cla FY18Q1     5.5
# 10    b_diff cla FY18Q1      NA
# 11         a cla FY18Q2    26.0
# 12         b cla FY18Q2 10000.0
# 13         c cla FY18Q2     6.2
# 14    b_diff cla FY18Q2 -2000.0
```

**DATA**

Notice that it is better to have `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

```
text <- "
parameter,car,qtr,val
a,a3,FY18Q1,23
b,a3,FY18Q1,10000
a,a3,FY18Q2,14
b,a3,FY18Q2,12000
a,cla,FY18Q1,15
b,cla,FY18Q1,12000
c,cla,FY18Q1,5.5
a,cla,FY18Q2,26
b,cla,FY18Q2,10000
c,cla,FY18Q2,6.2
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one algorithm:

1. Reshape the data to "wide" format, so that `qtr` and `car` form a unique row index, with the `parameter` column "spread" into columns
2. Within each car value, take the 1-period diff of the new `parameter_b` column
3. Reshape the data back to "long" format

Equivalent code, using reshape2 and dplyr:

```
# optional. you could just use `c(NA, diff(x))` below, but this is more general
padded_diff <- function(x, lag = 1L) {
  c(rep.int(NA, lag), diff(x, lag = lag))
}

df %>%
  dcast(car + qtr ~ parameter, value.var = "val") %>%
  mutate(b_diff = padded_diff(b)) %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("car", "qtr"), variable.name = "parameter") %>%
  arrange(car, qtr, parameter)
```

---

Here is another algorithm:

1. Group the data frame by `car`
2. Within each group, temporarily filter so that only rows with `paramter == "b"` are present
3. Take the 1-period diff of the `val` column
4. Remove the filter and ungroup

Equivalent code, using only dplyr, using a temporary table to simulate a "removable" filter:

```
make_b_diff_within_group <- function(df) {
  tmp <- df %>%
    filter(parameter == "b") %>%
    transmute(
      qtr = qtr,
      val = padded_diff(val),
      parameter = "b_diff")

  bind_rows(df, tmp)
}

df %>%
  group_by(car) %>%
  do(make_b_diff_within_group(.)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(car, qtr, parameter)
```

This second algorithm could be implemented using several other "split-apply-combine" paradigms, including the `tapply` or `by` functions in base R, the `ddply` function in the plyr package (an ancestor of dplyr by the same author), and the `split` method from dplyr, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385215/2954547).